# window.scrollBy() not working when binding with mousewheel event

Tags: javascript

when binding with mousewheel
function window.scrollBy() does nothing

> document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-section-wrap")[0].addEventListener('mousewheel',function(event){window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight); }, false);

But when binding with click event
function window.scrollBy() does scroll down

> document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-section-wrap")[0].addEventListener('click',function(event){window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight); }, false);

How could I do it with the mousewheel event?

Answer (score 0):

if you want bind this you can use

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        // scroll up
    }
    else {
        // scroll down
    }
});
```

you can listen on scroll event like this

```
window.onscroll = function() {
 //your logic
}
```

also can be done like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', effects);
```